# T-SQL : Calculating the % of rows that are not null

Tags: t-sql

So I must be daft - how would one calculate the number of rows that contain a value for addressline2?  aka the % of rows where Addressline2 is not null.

```
SELECT 
    (count(addressline2)/count(*))*1.000
FROM
    AdventureWorks2014.person.address
```

I thought that would do it, but it gives 0.

So I tried using common table expressions to grab a count of both scenarios, then divide them.  Also tried using a subquery to do the same.

This seem so simple - what am I missing?

[image: The AdventureWorks table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have the 1.0 multiplier in the wrong spot.

```
SELECT 
    (1.0 * count(addressline2)/count(*))
FROM
    AdventureWorks2014.person.address
```

Comment: Because it's the count(addressline2) that was becoming an integer 0...right, thanks!

Comment: @mmace31 No problem, been there myself. If you don't mind, make sure to accept the answer by clicking the check mark.

Comment: Yup, just had to wait for 5 (or however many) minutes to pass. Thanks again.

Comment: @mmace31 And, of course, the multiplier for percent would be `100.0`.